# Vaciar un arreglo en while

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente problema, en un arreglo que lleno en otra pagina tengo nombres de campos de una bd, lo que quiero es hacer una consulta select pero con los campos de mi arreglo

aqui traigo los campos de la bd que escojo en la pagina anterior y los imprimo, aqui no tengo problemas

```
foreach($_POST['opciones'] as $color){
        echo $color."<br>"; };
```

Esto no me resulta, en nombre1 esta la tabla y nombre2 los campos

```
$nombre1 = $_SESSION["bd"];
$nombre2 = $_POST['opciones'];
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $nombre1 ");

    $f = array();
    while($f = $res->fetch_array($nombre2)){

    echo $f[0] ;
}
```

Comment: Diríamos que es PHP, pero, ¿por qué no pusiste la etiqueta?

Comment: ¿Por qué estás pasando a `fetch_array` $nombre2 en argumento? Lo único que acepta es el tipo de retorno (array, asociativo o ambos).

Comment: Perdón por no poner la etiqueta, entonces en el while que coloco?? el res que tiene la consulta completa o $nombre2 que tiene el arreglo con los campos que tengo guardados.... seria asi  while($f = $nombre2->fetch_array())

Comment: Como lo tenías originalmente, pero quitando `$nombre2`, te devolverá un array (guardado en $f) con una linea de todos los campos de la base de datos. Si quieres limitar la query a los campos en `$nombre2` tendrías que hacerlo directamente en la  `query` (pero es peligroso, dado que $nombre2 proviene de un `$_POST` sin sanear) o bien filtrar `$f` dentro de cada iteración del `while`.

Comment: Si lo dejo como estaba me va a guardar toda la consulta con todos los campos yo solo quiero mostrar el contenido de los campos que seleccione y guarde en $campo2

Comment: y como viene armado $campo2?

Comment: Como he dicho, puedes interpolar $nombre2 en la query (`"SELECT ".join(",", $nombre2)." FROM $nombre1 "`) pero estás introduciendo una vulnerabilidad, ya que `$nombre2` proviene de `$_POST`, que puede ser manipulado por el usuario para inyectar lo que quiera en tu query. Si tienes un listado de todos los campos válidos posibles, podrías sanearlo fácilmente, pero no sé si es el caso.